# Android - unicode characters aren't displayed correctly

Tags: android, html, unicode, fonts, android-webview

I'm trying to load local html file:

```
    WebView webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    webView.getSettings().setDefaultTextEncodingName("utf-8");
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
```

index.html contains this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    </head >
    <body>
        რაღაც ტექსტი
    </body>
</html>
```

but it doesn't work. Can anyone help? 
P.S. that text is in Georgian

Edit: I've tried loading that text using almost every possible method I've found - loadDataWithBaseURL and loadData methods didn't work either.

Closed: Here is the problem: That version of Android didn't recognize Georgian characters.

Answer (score 5):

You can use HTML codes of UNICODE characters to display them in `WebView`.

Just replace the characters with their respective html code.

Refer [here](http://www.unicodemap.org/range/29/Georgian/) for Html codes of Georgian characters.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this approach;

```
String start = "<html><head><meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html' charset='UTF-8' /></head><body>";
String end = "</body></html>";

webView.loadData(start + YOURCONTENT + end,"text/html; charset=UTF-8", null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that your file is actually encoded as UTF-8.
 
Check if  your editor save it as UTF-8. It could be the problem.